# MongoDB start timeout after upgrade from 3.6 to 4.0

Tags: mongodb

Ever since I upgraded MongoDB from **3.6** to **4.0.24** mongod became so slow and does not start. It goes in timeout after 10 minutes (Start Timeout is 10 min in my mongod.service). Before the upgrade mongod was starting in around 6/7 minutes accordingly to the amount of data I have.

This is exactly my error:

````
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9df1b3a80f39cf7e7ccd6264a207518426a524f6
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-07-27T13:16:59.587+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { cloud: { monitoring: { free: { state: "runtime" } } }, config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", ipv6: false, maxIncomingConnections: 65536, port: 27017 }, operationProfiling: { mode: "off", slowOpThresholdMs: 100 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, security: { authorization: "disabled", javascriptEnabled: false }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", directoryPerDB: true, engine: "wiredTiger", journal: { enabled: true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { directoryForIndexes: false } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, logRotate: "rename", path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2021-07-27T13:16:59.588+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-07-27T13:16:59.588+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2021-07-27T13:16:59.588+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=15261M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2021-07-27T13:17:06.143+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1627391826:143222][2647:0x7f3ac1d73b80], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 4203/93334656 to 4204/256
2021-07-27T13:17:06.143+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1627391826:143879][2647:0x7f3ac1d73b80], txn-recover: Recovering log 4203 through 4204
2021-07-27T13:17:06.154+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1627391826:154899][2647:0x7f3ac1d73b80], txn-recover: Recovering log 4204 through 4204
2021-07-27T13:17:06.204+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1627391826:204351][2647:0x7f3ac1d73b80], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 6100013500000006
2021-07-27T13:17:06.259+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(1627390261, 6)
2021-07-27T13:17:06.260+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Triggering the first stable checkpoint. Initial Data: Timestamp(1627390261, 6) PrevStable: Timestamp(0, 0) CurrStable: Timestamp(1627390261, 6)
2021-07-27T13:17:06.261+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting to check the table logging settings for existing WiredTiger tables
2021-07-27T13:17:50.580+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting OplogTruncaterThread local.oplog.rs
2021-07-27T13:17:50.580+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 20015237 records totaling to 10481511730 bytes
2021-07-27T13:17:50.580+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Sampling the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2021-07-27T13:17:50.581+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Sampling from the oplog between Jul 19 03:45:47:6932 and Jul 27 12:51:01:6 to determine where to place markers for truncation
2021-07-27T13:17:50.581+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Taking 999 samples and assuming that each section of oplog contains approximately 200234 records totaling to 104857865 bytes
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 05:35:01:60
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 07:06:42:12701
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 07:39:30:22365
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 08:01:35:19048
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 09:59:07:7
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 10:54:18:14755
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 11:32:10:3429
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 12:09:00:22285
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 13:34:57:24670
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 13:38:22:17098
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 19 17:05:01:14
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 00:17:09:15395
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 00:27:08:10296
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 00:27:17:8132
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 00:28:03:2607
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 03:03:07:82
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 03:25:53:24257
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 03:46:11:17872
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 04:09:54:14830
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 06:15:04:36
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 10:11:01:9861
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 10:12:02:5243
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 11:00:04:805
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 11:57:51:15
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 13:45:09:25
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 15:21:26:5784
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 15:54:42:24704
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 20 18:56:08:26
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 00:17:24:3551
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 00:27:32:4720
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 00:27:41:11203
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 00:28:20:2048
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 03:24:50:11920
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 03:25:35:1387
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 03:44:45:22296
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 04:07:57:12493
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 06:55:02:60
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 08:36:19:13724
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 08:42:14:9873
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 08:56:11:19456
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 10:44:14:461
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 10:45:00:2597
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 11:10:00:37
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 21 11:46:06:54
...
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 26 12:07:38:3080
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 26 13:41:37:15715
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 26 17:10:03:14
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 00:17:10:1207
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 00:27:12:9832
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 00:28:08:17296
2021-07-27T13:17:50.710+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 03:27:22:1849
2021-07-27T13:17:50.711+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 04:17:34:2243
2021-07-27T13:17:50.711+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 07:54:49:2440
2021-07-27T13:17:50.711+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jul 27 09:36:00:12
2021-07-27T13:17:50.711+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger record store oplog processing took 130ms
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the global connection pool
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I SHARDING [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I COMMAND  [signalProcessingThread] Killing all open transactions
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I -        [signalProcessingThread] Killing all operations for shutdown
2021-07-27T13:33:39.710+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2021-07-27T13:33:39.711+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down free monitoring
2021-07-27T13:33:39.711+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time data capture
2021-07-27T13:33:39.711+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the HealthLog
2021-07-27T13:33:39.711+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Acquiring the global
```
````

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade path according Mongo documentation?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes I followed exactly this procedure https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-replica-set/